# What are all of jasmine expected conditions we can use for a test case?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, angular-e2e

There are several expected conditions such as toBe, toEqual,... that we can using in a test case.

```
expect('an expression').toBe('a value');
expect('an expression').toEqual('a value');
expect('an expression').*('a value');
```

I need to know domain of keywords that i can using instead of *

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more.

Comment: I want to define an enum for all of expected conditions, so i need to know how many conditions jasmine can support and what are them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly [this](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/matchers.html) page lists the jasmine matchers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below expect statement

```
expect(array).toContain(member);
```

This statement will pass if the entire `array` contains a particular `member`.

Hope it helps you